# How can I use hardhat.ethers inside a typescript task?

Tags: typescript, ethers.js, hardhat

Following code *can't find 'ethers'*:

```
import { HardhatUserConfig, task } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";

task('read',async () => {
    const contract = ethers.getContractFactory('AwesomeContract');
    // ...
})

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.15",
};

export default config;
```

Of course the developer can't do this:

```
import { ethers } from 'hardhat';
```

because it throws [HH9](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/errors#HH9).

Is it possible to use hardhat.ethers inside typescript tasks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before running a task, Hardhat injects the Hardhad Runtime Environment into the global scope, so you need to get `ethers` from it.

Check the [documentation example](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/create-task#advanced-usage):

```
task(
  "hello",
  "Prints 'Hello, World!'",
  async function (taskArguments, hre, runSuper) {
    console.log("Hello, World!");
  }
);
```

And another more real example:

`hardhat.config.ts`

```
import { HardhatUserConfig, task } from "hardhat/config"

import { updateItem } from "./scripts"

task("updateItem", "Update a listed NFT price")
  .addParam("id", "token ID")
  .addParam("price", "token new listing price")
  .setAction(async (args, hre) => {
    const tokenId = Number(args.id)
    const newPrice = String(args.price)
    await updateItem(hre, tokenId, newPrice)
  })

...
```

`updateItem.ts`

```
import { HardhatRuntimeEnvironment } from "hardhat/types"
import { NFTMarketplace } from "../typechain"

async function updateItem(hre: HardhatRuntimeEnvironment, tokenId: number, newPrice: string) {
  const nftMarketplace = (await hre.ethers.getContract("NFTMarketplace")) as NFTMarketplace
  ...
}

export default updateItem
```

Comment: Somehow overlooked the hre argument in the docs, It works. Anyway, if you have a /tasks dir, don't forget to add it to .tsconfig for this to work